# Update Statement in ORacle based on data in another 2 tables

Tags: oracle

I need to update one master table based on the join from another 2 tables.
Could anyoe please provide me with the best approach here as I need to update millions of records using this update.

Comment: Show us the tables and/or the SQL you've written so far.

Comment: I need to do something like this UPDATE TABLEB set f_key =(select p_key from table A join table c on tableA.id = tableC.id)

Comment: share the details , with some of code that you tried

Comment: The example you've provided will work *as long as the subquery returns zero or one rows* (if zero rows, `f_key` will be set to `NULL`; if one row, `f_key` will be set to the value returned by the subquery). If you have further problems please post table info and some sample data. This is very doable but it can be a bit tricky, so a generic answer probably won't help you here.

Comment: UPDATE table_A SET sk_id = 
SELECT sk_id FROM (SELECT sk_id,t_ver.tid,t_ver.tstamp,t_ver.tnumber,t_ver.sname FROM t_ver,d_ver,t_ird WHERE tsetid = 91000
AND t_ver.tid = d_ver.tid
AND t_ver.tstamp = d_ver.tstamp
AND t_ver.tnumber = d_ver.tnumber
AND t_ver.sname = d_ver.sname
AND t_ird.ird = t_ver.ird ) TV
WHERE table_A.ird = TV.ird

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be useful:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   ID INT,
   STR VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE B(
   ID INT,
   STR VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO A VALUES(1,'A1');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(2,'A2');
INSERT INTO A VALUES(3,'A3');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(1,'B');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(3,'C');
INSERT INTO B VALUES(4,'D');

/*HERE THE QUERY!!*/
MERGE INTO A
USING ( select ID, STR
          from B ) B
ON ( A.ID = B.ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET  A.STR = B.STR;
```

Here other query, but maybe will have problems with NULL values (try [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86558/3)):

```
UPDATE A
SET STR = (
  SELECT STR
  FROM B
  WHERE A.ID = B.ID);
```

You can try this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86558/1)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is **Correlated update** statement, Check this link [Oracle correlated UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113285/oracle-correlated-update)

Comment: Check up here my post, this is an example of "Correlated update".

Comment: We both answered around the same time, you gave him an example and I told him what it was :)